# Why does this SQL execute but not update anything?

Tags: php, sql

For some reason or another, this sql is executing and outputting: 
successfully added the following paypal button to this product... But it's not updating. I'd appreciate any help on this.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submitedform'])) {

    if ($_POST['paypal']) {

        $paypal=$_POST['paypal'];

        $id = $_GET['id'];

        $query = "UPDATE `video_info` SET paypal_button_html='".$paypal
        ."' WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($id) ."'";

        mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        echo "successfully added the following paypal button to this product:
        <br /><br />
        {$paypal}";
    }
}

?>

<? 
if ($_GET['id']) { 
?>
<h1>Add PayPal Button In for this product:</h1>
<form action="add_paypal.php" method="POST"> 
    *Paypal button html: <br><textarea rows="2" cols="20" name="paypal"></textarea><br> 
    <input type="hidden" name="submitedform" value="true" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Add paypal button in for this product"> 
</form>

<? 

} else {

    echo "You can not come to this page manually."; 
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few problems:

- You were not being consistent in sanitising your Database Input
- You did not have clear validation rules
- Your form was not setting the `$_GET['id']` field (so the database submission was always failing)

Amended code:

```
<?php

// Init an Array to hold any error messages
$errors = array();

if( isset( $_REQUEST['submitedform'] ) ){

  // Validate the required fields
  if( !isset( $_POST['paypal'] ) || $_POST['paypal']=='' )
    $errors['paypal'] = 'No value for "paypal"';
  if( !isset( $_GET['id'] ) || !is_numeric( $_GET['id'] ) )
    $errors['id'] = 'No value for "id"';

  // If Validation was successful
  if( !$errors ){

    // Prepare the Variables for Database Usage
    $paypal = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['paypal'] );
    $id = (int) $_GET['id'];

    // Template and Complete the SQL Query
    $sqlTpl = 'UPDATE `video_info` SET paypal_button_html="%s" WHERE `id` = %s';
    $sqlStr = sprintf( $sqlTpl , $paypal , $id );

    // Submit the Query
    if( !mysql_query( $sqlStr ) ){

      // Something went wrong
      $errors[] = 'An error occured when submitting the data to the database';

    }else{

      // Submitted OK
      echo 'Successfully added the following paypal button to this product:'.$paypal;

    }

  }

}

// Check for any errors
if( $errors ){

  // Show errors to user
  echo 'The following errors occurred:';
  echo '<ul><li>'.implode( '</li><li>' , $errors ).'</li></ul>';

}

?>

<? 
if( isset( $_GET['id'] ) && is_int( $_GET['id'] ) ){
?>
<h1>Add PayPal Button In for this product:</h1>
<form action="add_paypal.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" method="POST"> 
  *Paypal button html: <br><textarea rows="2" cols="20" name="paypal"></textarea><br> 
  <input type="hidden" name="submitedform" value="true" /> 
  <input type="submit" value="Add paypal button in for this product"> 
</form>

<? 

} else {

    echo "You can not come to this page manually."; 
}

?>
```

This code...

1. Includes the `id` in the form's action URL
2. Checks for the submission
3. Validates the submitted values
4. Creates the Database Query
5. Submits the Query
6. Checks the Query worked OK

**AMENDED:** Replaced `is_int()` with `is_numeric()` as, after RTFMing, I found that a string, comprised of only digits, will apparently return `false` if tested with `is_int()`.

Comment: omg thank you so much!!!!!!! Yeah I saw the is_int thing and replaced it. Thank you so much for doing that for me :)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Please, use `$_REQUEST` OR `$_GET` OR `$_POST` but not all 3 of them.

Also, why don't you `mysql_real_escape_string` the variable `$_POST['paypal']` ?

Comment: I use Request to avoid a duplicate submit.

I use Get because I get the data from another page that sends it to this page through the url.

I took out mysql_real_escape_string because I thought that was the problem. 

Thanks for your time.

Comment: So, maybe the id just isn't existing at all? This way, the statement succeeds, but doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You mix `$_GET` and `$_POST` variables. You should use either GET or POST, but not both. If this is a post request, change `$_GET['id']` to `$_POST['id']`.

In this case, the update doesn't fail because of `where id = ''`. This doesn't update anything, because there's no `id` with an empty string. But it also doesn't fail, since it is a valid update statement.

Comment: I had to grab the id value from the url because it gets sent this data from another page.

Comment: I'd echo the the `$query` anyway, just to see, whether it's really the update statement you think it should be.